# What will be the Kindle file type replacement for when mobi files are deprecated?

Tags: epub, calibre, conversion, mobi, linux

What is the current or preferred file type to [convert](https://askubuntu.com/a/1352730/847449) an `epub` to for a `kindle`?

Assuming `paperwhite`, or similar relatively recent model.  My `kindle` has backlight but isn't waterproof like the `paperwhite` -- so relatively recent.

More asking going forward:  assuming that `mobi` will be deprecated at some point, what's the replacement?

Comment: Why do you think .mobi will be depreciated?

Answer (score 1):

The current file extension is .kfx (According to Wikipedia this is "Kindle Format 10" )